# Go to specific dynamic url on click in table with specific cell data reference - Jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamic-data, response.redirect

I have an html table like below

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| col1  | col2  | col3  | col4  | col5  | col6    | col7    | col8    | col9    |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5 | button1 | button2 | button3 | button4 |
+-------+---------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| data6 | data7 | data8 | data9 | data0 | button1 | button2 | button3 | button4 |
+---------------+-------+-------+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

columns 6-9 contains buttons with corresponding names and ids as shown.

What I want is,

When the user click but 1 in row 1, the page should go to a url `www.example.com/sample.php?but1=data1` and when the user click but 1 in row 2, the page should go to a url `www.example.com/sample.php?but1=data6`.
similarly, the buttons 2, 3 and 4 should redirect the page to `www.example.com/sample2.php?but1=data1`, `www.example.com/sample3.php?but1=data1`, `www.example.com/sample4.php?but1=data1` in row 1 and  `www.example.com/sample2.php?but1=data6`, `www.example.com/sample3.php?but1=data6`, and `www.example.com/sample4.php?but1=data6` in row 2.

How can I make this possible using jquery??

The table contains more rows than shown here..

Here is my table

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<table style="width: 100%" id="mytable" name="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td>col1</td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
        <td>col4</td>
        <td>col5</td>
        <td>col6</td>
        <td>col7</td>
        <td>col8</td>
        <td>col9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td name="datacol" id="datacol">data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
        <td>data4</td>
        <td>data5</td>
        <td id="data1" class="button1" name="button1" style="cursor:pointer">button1</td>
        <td id="data1" class="button2" name="button2" style="cursor:pointer">button2</td>
        <td id="data1" class="button3" name="button3" style="cursor:pointer">button3</td>
        <td id="data1" class="button4" name="button4" style="cursor:pointer">button4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td name="datacol" id="datacol">data6</td>
        <td>data7</td>
        <td>data8</td>
        <td>data9</td>
        <td>data10</td>
        <td id="data6" class="button1" name="button1" style="cursor:pointer">button1</td>
        <td id="data6" class="button2" name="button2" style="cursor:pointer">button2</td>
        <td id="data6" class="button3" name="button3" style="cursor:pointer">button3</td>
        <td id="data6" class="button4" name="button4" style="cursor:pointer">button4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the button cells are modified table ells with pointer cursor ;)

the url distribution should be like;

**first row**
button1: `www.example.com/1111.php?aa=data1`
button2: `www.example2.com/2222.php?bb=data1`
button3: `www.example3.com/3333.php?cc=data1`
button4: `www.example4.com/4444.php?dd=data1`

**second row**
button1: `www.example.com/1111.php?aa=data6`
button2: `www.example2.com/2222.php?bb=data6`
button3: `www.example3.com/3333.php?cc=data6`
button4: `www.example4.com/4444.php?dd=data6`

I need a code like this;

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.button1').click(function() {
   document.location.href='the_link_to_go_to.html';  
        });
        $('.button2').click(function() {
   document.location.href='the_link_to_go_to.html';    
        });
        $('.button3').click(function() {
   document.location.href='the_link_to_go_to.html';     
        });
        $('.button4').click(function() {
   document.location.href='the_link_to_go_to.html';     
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance.. :)

blasteralfred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it..
First of all I thank `Vivek`, `Prescott`, `JustcallmeDrago`, `BiAiB` and `Gordon`... :) Thanks guyz..

I made it through

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.button1').click(function() {
   window.location = "www.example.com/1111.php?aa=" + this.id;
    });
    $('.button2').click(function() {
   window.location = "www.example2.com/2222.php?bb=" + this.id;
    });
    $('.button3').click(function() {
   window.location = "www.example3.com/3333.php?cc=" + this.id;
    });
    $('.button4').click(function() {
   window.location = "www.example4.com/4444.php?dd=" + this.id;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you should at least vote up to each answer.......and whatever you have updated now,is totally different from your earlier question...so please make sure before posting a question that your doubt is clear...

Answer (score 1):

put this in a javaScript file

```
$(function () {
    $("#myUniqueTable input[type=button]").click(function () {
         tdValue= $(this).parents('tr').find('td').eq(0).text() ;
         columnIndex = $(this).parents('tr').find('td').index(this)
         url= 'www.example.com/sample'+columnIndex +'.php?but1='+tdValue    
        $(location).attr('href',url);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have added my table to my question.. Have a look at it.... can you post the code for me??

Comment: have you got your solution are not?

Comment: @blasteralfred - if you modify the code Vivek provided, change #myUnqiueTable to #mytable it should work. If it doesn't, please post and let us know what error your getting or what you see happening

Comment: no.. not doing anything.. I need something like     <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.button1').click(function() {
//go to first address//
    });
    $('.button2').click(function() {
//go to second address//    
    });
    $('.button3').click(function() {
//go to third address//    
    });
    $('.button4').click(function() {
//go to fourth address//    
    });
});
</script>

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way:

1. name your cells id according to their col/row like  `<td id="myTable1-3">...</td>`
2. use a  delegate Handler on the table
3. retrieve row and col number from cell's id
4. redirect

code:

```
 $('#yourtable').delegate( "td", "click", function() {

        var id = $(this).attr( "id" );

        // There're far better ways to get those number with regex or whatever
        var pos = id.split('myTable')[1]; 
        var col = parseInt( pos.split('-')[0] );
        var row = parseInt( pos.split('-')[1] );

        // Now you have the col and row numbers of the clicked cell, 
        // you can generate your url and open it as needed

    } );
```

Comment: i think he want to append first cell data